# Powershell Use Functions and Pass Data

Tags: powershell, function, return, arguments, return-value

The goal of my script is push the current copy of a file from the file share to a PC with checks. My script was working until I tried to convert it from one big script into functions. I probably misunderstood how they work, I am not a programmer. The script works if the data in the settings section is pre-sanitized ($clientServer= \\server\ and $sharePath= share\Edge_IE_Mode\) but fails if it is not (functions dont appear to be changing data). Could someone help out?

```
# User logon Script that checks if the fileshare and XML file are available, then pulls the XML file to local

################ Settings ################
# Path of server file (directory)
# Server: \\SERVER\
$clientServer = 'SERVER'
# Server path: share\Edge_IE_Mode\
$sharePath = '\share\Edge_IE_Mode\'


################ Variables ################
# Path of local file (directory)
$localDirectory = 'C:\Users\'+$env:UserName+'\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Edge_IE_Mode'

# Full path of the local file
$localFile = $localDirectory+'Edge_IE_Mode_Sites.xml'

# Path of server file (directory)
$remoteDirectory = $clientServer+$sharePath
# $remoteDirectory = '' # Defined later as $remoteDirectory = $clientServer+$sharePath

# Full path of the server file 
$remoteFile = $remoteDirectory+'Edge_IE_Mode_Sites.xml'


################ Functions ################
Function clientServerSanitize ($clientServer) # formats $clientServer
{
    # add \\ to beginning of $clientServer
    if (-not($clientServer -like '\\*'))
    {
        Write-Host "clientServer value: "$clientServer
        Write-Host "Adding leading '\\' to clientServer variable"
        $clientServer = '\\'+$clientServer
        Write-Host "clientServer \\ IF STATEMENT Output: "$clientServer
    }

    # add \ to end of $clientServer
    if (-not($clientServer -like '*\'))
    {
        Write-Host "clientServer value: "$clientServer
        Write-Host "Adding trailing '\' to clientServer variable"
        $clientServer = $clientServer+'\'
        Write-Host "clientServer \ IF STATEMENT Output: "$clientServer
    }
    return $clientServer
}

Function sharePathSanitize ($sharePath) # formats $sharePath
{
    # remove \ from beginning of $sharePath
    if ($sharePath -like '\*')
    {
        # Write-Host "sharePath value: "$sharePath
        Write-Host "Removing leading '\' from sharePath variable"
        $sharePath = $sharePath.substring(1,$sharePath.Length-1)
        # Write-Host "sharePath \ IF STATEMENT Output: "$sharePath
        
    }
    return $sharePath
}

Function remoteDirectoryUpdate($clientServer, $sharePath)
{
    $remoteDirectory = $clientServer+$sharePath
    $remoteFile = $remoteDirectory+'Edge_IE_Mode_Sites.xml'
    $remoteDirectory
    $remoteFile
    return $remoteDirectory
}

Function localDirectoryCheck
{
    # if localDirectory folder does not exist in AppData
    if (-not(Test-Path -Path $localDirectory)) {
        #Create directory if it does not exist
        Write-Host "Path not found, creating folder"
        try 
        {
            New-Item -Path $localDirectory.substring(0,$localDirectory.Length - 12) -Name 'Edge_IE_Mode' -ItemType 'directory'
            Write-Host "Folder Created successfully"
        } catch {
            throw $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
}

Function fileShareCopy($remoteDirectory)
{
    try 
    {
        remoteDirectoryUpdate
        Write-Host "Attempting to pull from Fileshare"
        # Test Path to fileshare
        #$tempVar = 'filesystem::'+$remoteDirectory
        #Test-Path $tempVar
        $remoteDirectory
        Test-Path $remoteDirectory

        # Copy file from share
        $remoteFile
        $localDirectory
        Copy-Item $remoteFile -Destination $localDirectory
        Write-Host "Edge_IE_Mode_Sites.xml copied from Fileshare"
    } catch {
        throw $_.Exception.Message
    }
}


Function pause ($message)
{
    # Check if running Powershell ISE
    if ($psISE)
    {
        Write-Host "Press OK to exit...."
        $message = "Press OK to Exit"
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$message")
    }
    else
    {
        $message = "Press any key to exit...."
        Write-Host "$message" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $x = $host.ui.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
    }
}


################ Script ################
clientServerSanitize($clientServer)
sharePathSanitize($sharePath)
localDirectoryCheck
remoteDirectoryUpdate($clientServer, $sharePath)
fileShareCopy($remoteDirectory)
pause
```

Comment: One thing to change is how you are calling your functions.  Unlike a lot of other languages, PowerShell functions don't use parentheses in calls.  For example `clientServerSanitize($clientServer)` should be `clientServerSanitize $clientServer` or, more clearly, `clientServerSanitize -ClientServer $clientServer` - the function arguments become parameters to the function call, just like standard cmdlets.

Comment: Aside from the syntax problem that boxdog points out: what does it mean for the variables in the Settings section to _not_ be sanitized? Where would such values come from? Please update your question to clarify, and include a _specific_ description of what does and doesn't happen, including error messages, if any.

Comment: ```clientServerSanitize($clientServer)``` doesn't update the value of the ```$clientServer``` variable in your top-level script - it just returns the sanitized value. Inside the ```clientServerSanitize``` function the **parameter** ```$clientServer``` "hides" the top-level **variable** with the same name, and any changes made to ```$clientServer``` inside the function are lost when the function exits. However, since you're returning the modified value, you can just assign it back to the variable in the main script - e.g. ```$clientServer = clientServerSanitize -ClientServer $clientServer```.